# Creating a webhook in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a chrome extension ingesting data from various web pages I visit and storing it to a database (Python/Flask)

I also have a dashboard visualizing that database (using react-create-app node/react/redux).

I want the dashboard to be automatically updated every time I add/delete/modify a record in the database.

From what I understand that is specifically what a webhook is for.

What I want to do is create a "listener" on the database so that every time a change is made, it will fire off a request to the node server.

A few things: 1.) How do I create "something" to listen for changes in a database? 2.) Normally my webpage initiates a web request and listens for data in the call back. How do I structure it so it just "listens" for new updates?

Comment: What do you mean by 'storing into a database(python/Flask)' ? Flask is a web framework it doesn't store anything. Where exactly does the data get stored ? In a file? MySQL ? Mongo ?

Comment: It sounds like you want your server to update the client when something changes in the data model. Is this right? Typcally webhooks refer to something different, where a server makes an http post to another server to notify about a change in the data model.

Comment: Django has something called `signals`, and I think Flask has a similar thing - check this out: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/signals/

Comment: When you request a page from the node server on every request you receive in the flask app that handles CRUD changes you effectively created a web hook (one server requesting or posting another). You may want to offload this to a background thread or job system, like beanstalkd. Giving you asynchronous webhook calls. If you want the page you monitor to also update you might be interested in web sockets.

Comment: @lee-pai-long yea, im using SQL alchemy to store into a mysql db, sorry assumed someone would understand that

Comment: @alexanderbird yes, that is correct

Comment: @alexanderbird `to notify a change in the data model` is that different than a change in the database? this would be a flask server to a node server

Comment: Yes, I meant those two things to mean the same thing. Now when you say "flask server to node server" it sounds like there is no browser involved. Is that true? Where does the web client come into it?

Comment: @alexanderbird React is running on the node server (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

Comment: Well, not quite. React runs in the browser, the node server hosts the html and JavaScript, and the browser requests the html and JavaScript from the server, and then runs react. I've got a diagram going for you, expect an answer in a moment here

Comment: @ alexanderbird right, that makes sense.

Comment: So after all this @Remco is right what you need is websocket, I recomend the use of the [Flask-SocketIO](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO) extension. You'll have a nice and simple example [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent)

Comment: @Remco can you put this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @lee-pai-long thank you!

Comment: @morganallen done, thank you. Glad you gained clarity about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request a page from the node server on every request you receive in the flask app that handles CRUD changes you effectively created a web hook (one server requesting or posting another). You may want to offload this to a background thread or job system, like beanstalkd. Giving you asynchronous webhook calls. If you want the page you monitor to also update you might be interested in web sockets.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like this is what you're looking for:

```
+- Browser --------+    +---- Browser ---------------+
| Chrome extension |    |    React dashboard         |
+---+--------------+    +-+----+----------------+----+
    |                     |    ^                |
    |                     |    |                |
[C] +         [B]+--------+    |            [A] |
   POST       open a           |  [D]          GET
  (http)      websocket     send websocket    (http)
    |            |      +---message             |
    v            |      |                       v
+-- Server A +---------------+     + Server B --+----+
|                v      |    |     |                 |
| +--------------+------+-+  |     |  +-----------+  |
| | Flask                 |  |     |  |  Node     |  |
| +-----------------------+  |     |  | (hosting  |  |
| +-----------------------+  |     |  |   React)  |  |
| | DB                    |  |     |  +-----------+  |
| +-----------------------+  |     |                 |
+----------------------------+     +-----------------+
```

- **[A]** From your web browser, you load your React dashboard from your node server
- **[B]** Your react app opens a websocket connection to your python server when it initializes. A websocket allows two way communication between a browser client and a server - see details below.
- **[C]** Some time later, in your browser, your chrome extension makes an http call to your python server, which updates the database
- **[D]** Your python server, after updating the database, sends a websocket message to your react app using the websocket connection that it already established. Your react app then updates the dashboard with the latest data sent via websocket.

## Websockets

**[Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)** is a protocol that allows two way communication between a server and a browser client.

## You'll Need To:

1. Update your react app so it creates a websocket connection and listens for update messages. [There's an npm package for that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-websocket), but I've never used it before.
2. Update your python server to accept websocket connections and send websocket messages for every update. [There's a python package for flask that implements websockets](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - I've used this one a few years ago for a school project and it did the trick.

<sub>**By the way**: You don't need two servers for this. Your node server can handle the database saves, or your python/flask server could serve the React app.</sub>

Comment: **offtopic but** @alexanderbird did you use a particular app to make the schema ? If so I would love a link :)